# Convert JSON to List<Map<String, List<String>>> without overusing dynamic

Tags: dart

Given the following JSON string

```
[
    {
        "popular": []
    },
    {
        "recommended": [
            "privacy",
            "security",
            "IFTTT",
            "mobile",
            "location",
            "Pocket",
            "advertising",
            "Instapaper",
            "data",
            "surveillance"
        ]
    }
]
```

How would I go about converting this to `List<Map<String, List<String>>>` without overusing `dynamic`?

This is what I have currently:

```
response // List<dynamic>
        .map((i) => (i as Map<String, dynamic>).map((String key, dynamic value) =>
            MapEntry<String, List<String>>(key, List<String>.from(value))))
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as minimal as I can get it - the static type is correctly `List<Map<String, List<String>>>` with only a bit of repetition with the `as` casts.

```
  var typed = (response as List) //skip this `as` if it's already a List
      .map((v) => (v as Map)
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, List<String>>(k, List.from(v))))
      .toList();
```

Inference fills in the rest for you.